# Do Constellar Delegates take extra chaos damage?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

During Phase 3 of the Argus encounter, Constellar Delegates spawn, and shortly suffer debuffs amplifying the damage they take from specific elements. Some spells have two elements - Hand of Gul'dan, for example, is "shadowflame", which counts as both shadow and fire and therefore deals bonus damage to either the shadow or fire delegates.

Which elements, if any, does chaos damage count as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***All*** of them.

*Chaos* is one of the so-called *multi-school* types and includes:

- Arcane
- Fire
- Frost
- Holy
- Nature
- Shadow
- Physical

So basically *Chaos* has all 7 schools and with that is the one with the most schools. Ranked 2nd is *Elemental* with just 3 schools (Fire, Frost, Nature).

So in that mentioned Argus encounter you're lucky.. All adds will take amplified damage from Chaos skills.

Comment: I feared I wouldn't get bonuses against any of them, but I didn't dare hope I'd be getting bonus chaos damage against the physical and holy Delegates. Definitely worth switching to demonbolt if I get the boost for every delegate (also a reason to envy havoc demon hunters, who do way more chaos damage than I can)